# Create fedex international freight shipment using WSDL

Tags: php, wsdl, fedex

I am in process of currently integrating Fedex API for international shipments, I am  currently stuck in creating International shipments using WSDL.

I referred the Fedex WSDL developer guide, but I didn't found any sample request for fedex international freight shipment.

If anyone do know the way to sample request for creating fedex international freight using WSDL, Please let me know.

Thanks,